# Eclipse JDT compiler can incrementally compile Java Source and notify what classes compiled?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

Now I want to implement this case:

If java source file modified, I compile dynamically the java source file to class file.
Then I want to know what classes are recompiled so that I can redefine and reload them.

Or someone have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with a [resource change listener](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html)